# How do Triggered effects handle whether they hit?

Tags: traps, mutants-and-masterminds-3e, triggered-actions

**Triggered** can be added to effects of any range, Close, Ranged, or Perception, and possibly also Area effects. Normally, Close and Ranged attacks require an attack roll to hit. If one is trying to plant a Triggered effect on a target (say, sticking a time bomb on a hostage to distract the heroes or shooting a laser-trip mine to a distant wall), it makes sense to use an attack roll. And if it's an Area effect (such as a claymore mine), it makes sense that there is only the Dodge save to reduce the damage. And something like a single-shot drone would do a ranged attack roll to hit the first intruder it sports. But what happens if it's a bear-trap or a smaller mine, where the intent is a single target who triggers it by passing through the square?

Should there be an attack roll made when setting it to model placing it in a way to maximize the chance of hitting the target? A Dodge save to model the person recognizing the danger and dodging it (probably for no damage since it's not an actual Area attack)? How ought that to interact with Perception or Area attacks?

Comment: FWIW, I tagged Steve Kenson, the system creator, [here](https://twitter.com/FuzzyDugganSC/status/1628803811094544388). I will let you know if I get a reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apparently asked and was answered twice, although I'm only finding [the second time](https://www.youtube.com/live/pqGNdwhvWHc?feature=share&t=2522) right now.

> **Steve Kenson**: Yeah, um, it— it depends very much on what triggers the effect and what the effect is, um, if the effect is directed then generally the answer is yes, it has, you know, like if the— the triggered effect is a blast shoots out of, you know, a point, um, then yeah, it has an attack roll. Uh, if it's an area effect, and a lot of triggered effects are, then obviously it
> doesn't. Likewise if it's a perception triggered effect or if it's an effect that is triggered, um, by the thing that it is targeting, like the most common example being you touch something and trigger an effect then, uh, the effect happens because you're touching it and it wouldn't need an attack roll in that instance, you know, like, such as a trap where you're, you know, touching something with a live wire.

....

> **Troy**: ... So, uh, and Claude says you'd use the trap setter's accuracy for that?
> **Steve**: Generally speaking? Yes.
> **Alex Thomas**: Yeah, use your better discretion. I mean if it makes sense for an attack roll to take place, have an attack roll take place, but if not, don't do it.
> **Steve** Yeah, indeed.